# ExpandableLayout not working in android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using ExpandableLayout from this library :

https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

its work good , but in android 6 it does not work ! just show my data and Non-clickable layout .

i input library in my project 
here is the Codes library i use it:

```
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.Transformation;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    public class ExpandableLayout extends RelativeLayout
    {
    private Boolean isAnimationRunning = false;
    private Boolean isOpened = false;
    private Integer duration;
    private FrameLayout contentLayout;
    private FrameLayout headerLayout;
    private Animation animation;

    public ExpandableLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        final View rootView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.view_expandable, this);
        headerLayout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_expandable_headerlayout);
        final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableLayout);
        final int headerID = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandableLayout_el_headerLayout, -1);
        final int contentID = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandableLayout_el_contentLayout, -1);
        contentLayout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_expandable_contentLayout);

        if (headerID == -1 || contentID == -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HeaderLayout and ContentLayout cannot be null!");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
            if (isInEditMode())
                return;
        }

        duration = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ExpandableLayout_el_duration, getContext().getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime));
        final View headerView = View.inflate(context, headerID, null);
        headerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        headerLayout.addView(headerView);
        final View contentView = View.inflate(context, contentID, null);
        contentView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        contentLayout.addView(contentView);
        contentLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        headerLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!isAnimationRunning)
                {
                    if (contentLayout.getVisibility() == VISIBLE)
                        collapse(contentLayout);
                    else
                        expand(contentLayout);

                    isAnimationRunning = true;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            isAnimationRunning = false;
                        }
                    }, duration);
                }
            }
        });

        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    private void expand(final View v)
    {
        v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        animation = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
            {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1)
                    isOpened = true;
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (interpolatedTime == 1) ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }


            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        animation.setDuration(duration);
        v.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    private void collapse(final View v)
    {
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        animation = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if(interpolatedTime == 1)
                {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isOpened = false;
                }
                else{
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        animation.setDuration(duration);
        v.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public Boolean isOpened()
    {
        return isOpened;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        if (!isAnimationRunning)
        {
            expand(contentLayout);
            isAnimationRunning = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    isAnimationRunning = false;
                }
            }, duration);
        }
    }

    public FrameLayout getHeaderLayout()
    {
        return headerLayout;
    }

    public FrameLayout getContentLayout()
    {
        return contentLayout;
    }

    public void hide()
    {
        if (!isAnimationRunning)
        {
            collapse(contentLayout);
            isAnimationRunning = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    isAnimationRunning = false;
                }
            }, duration);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayoutAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener animationListener) {
        animation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    }
}
```

and where i use this library

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


                  <expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
                xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/firstshahr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_headershahr"
                expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_contentshahr"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />
            <expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
            android:id="@+id/firststar"
                xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_headerstar"
            expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_contentstar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
            <expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
                android:id="@+id/firsttarikh"
                xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_headertarikh"
                expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_contenttarikh"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />
             <expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstghaza"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_headerghaza"
            expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_contentghaza"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           />
            <expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
            android:id="@+id/firsthavapeymaei"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_headerhavapeymaei"
            expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_contenthavapeyaei"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           />
            <expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstmodat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_headermodat"
            expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_contentmodat"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           />

</LinearLayout>
```

view_headerstar.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:contextClickable="true">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/turlahzeakhari"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="درجه هتل"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tour_index"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/archive_star"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tour_index55"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/archive_fp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

view_contentstar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/re12"
    >

    <ListView
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/listfilter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textDirection="rtl" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) It is very simple and useful!

Comment: thank you but i want solved my problem with this library